# Why link error with following simple OpenGL ES2 shader?

Tags: ios, linker, opengl-es-2.0

Just simple programming with follow(from [here](http://mobileorchard.com/getting-started-with-opengl-es-20-on-the-iphone-3gs/))

```
float odd = floor(mod(gl_FragCoord.y, 2.0));  // problems come from this line 
gl_FragColor = vec4(v_color.x, v_color.y, v_color.z, odd);
```

But it can not pass the link.

I know it is quite simple,but it is quiet new for me, I just want to go through this problem.
Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Just to be sure, you are placing these lines in your fragment shader, correct?  Also, what does `glGetShaderInfoLog()` report in the log as a compile error for this line?

Comment: thanks ! Yes, just replace from creating project directly from xcode4 template. And with error like these 2011-05-01 11:12:21.307 OpenGL2[1577:207] Failed to validate program: 1
2011-05-01 11:12:21.323 OpenGL2[1577:207] Program validate log:
Validation Failed: Link error:
  Program is not successfully linked.